# adding an or function to excel formula if statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an if-statement that searches a cell to see if it contains one of multiple values and if the value exists then to show a value from another cell.

So, in the cell `A1` I have the following code:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV10)),"")
```

This code searches cell `G10` for `SLR`, `SMR` and `BRL`.

If the value exists then it shows the value from cell `AV10`

I want to add an or-statement, so that I can have multiple if-statements like this

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV10)),""), OR,
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"TTT","RRR","BBB"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV11)),""), OR, 
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"ZZZ","XXX","YYY"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV12)),""), OR, 
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LLL","MMM","QQQ"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV11)),""), OR, 
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV13)),""),"ERROR")
```

So, what we have here is one large if statement that checks to see if a cell contains a set of three values `"SLR", "SMR", OR "BRL"` and if it does then show the link in AV10 and if the cell does not contain these three values but inStead contains `"TTT", "RRR", "BBB"` then show the value in `AV11` and so on

Can anyone please help me with this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to replace the empty string in the else part of the if statement with the next if statement.  Then the word ERROR is in the last else of the last if statement. Like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV10)),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"TTT","RRR","BBB"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV11)),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"ZZZ","XXX","YYY"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV12)),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LLL","MMM","QQQ"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV13)),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP"},G10)),CONCATENATE(HYPERLINK(AV14)),
 "ERROR")))))
```

I don't know why you have the CONCATENATE function there - it concatenates it's arguments but each of them only has one argument so it doesn't actually do anything.  Unless I don't understand what you have done, this should do the same thing:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV10),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"TTT","RRR","BBB"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV11),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"ZZZ","XXX","YYY"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV12),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LLL","MMM","QQQ"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV13),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV14),
 "ERROR")))))
```

If AV10 were to contain  `=HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg","Send Email")`  then a formula of  `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV10),"")`  would make a hyperlink of the words Send Email but clicking them is not a valid address.

So what you really want to do is change AV10 to either  `=HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg")`  or just  `\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg` and change the forumla I gave you to:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV10,"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"TTT","RRR","BBB"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV11,"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"ZZZ","XXX","YYY"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV12,"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LLL","MMM","QQQ"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV13,"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP"},G10)),HYPERLINK(AV14,"Send Email"),
 "ERROR")))))
```

Now the calculated hyperlink is displayed as Send Email but has the right address (you can see the address in the tool tip when you hover over the cell).  If you don't like having AV10 - AV14 displaying the actual address and you want them to show Send Email as well then the formula needs to extract the address of the hyperlinks in AV10 - AV14.

According to http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/12/13/get-the-url-from-an-excel-hyperlink/ there is no built in function for that but if you add the VBA function on that page then AV10 can remain as  `=HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg","Send Email")`  and your formula would look like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"SLR","SMR","BRL"},G10)),HYPERLINK(HLink(AV10),"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"TTT","RRR","BBB"},G10)),HYPERLINK(HLink(AV11),"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"ZZZ","XXX","YYY"},G10)),HYPERLINK(HLink(AV12),"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"LLL","MMM","QQQ"},G10)),HYPERLINK(HLink(AV13),"Send Email"),
 IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"UUU","KKK","PPP"},G10)),HYPERLINK(HLink(AV14),"Send Email"),
 "ERROR")))))
```

Now everything displays Send Email but all the hyperlinks should work.

Comment: thanks for this, it seems to be working although when you click on the hyperlink it says can not open the specified file

Comment: @tomjones I guess it depends on what is in A10 - A13.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Its actually AV10 - AV 14 but I've changed this in my code,  each of them contains a similar link like this "=HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg","Send Email")"

Comment: @tomjones So your original forumla didn't work either.  The address of the Hyperlink it is creating is the words Send Email.  If A10 actually had `=HYPERLINK("\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg")` or even just `\\UKSH000-FILE06\Purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\EMAIL_PLANT.msg` it would work.  I will edit the answer

Comment: the original link did work, the send email is the name of the link